# Error en java "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Tags: java, excepciones

Porque razon me sale  este error de excepcion al utilizar el iterator en esta linea:

```
/*if((itTrayectos.next().getIdEinicial() == idEInicial) && (itTrayectos.next().getIdEfinal() == idEFinal))*/

package Grafos;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import graphsDSESIUCLM.*;
public class Grafos {
public static void main(String [] args){
    /*
     * - menor o igual que 300 de duracion.
     * - legada y salida a la misma estacion no se considera trayecto.
     * - Trayecto efecturado de origen y destino con las mismas estaciones por diferentes ciudadanos se considera una sola estacion.
     */

    //variables para guaradar   
    int idViaje;
    int duracionSeg;
    int idEInicial;
    int idEFinal;
    double longEInicial;
    double longEFinal;
    double latEInicial;
    double latEFinal;
    //Leer archivo
    String archivo = "MetroBikeShare_2016_Q3_trips.csv";
    Scanner entrada = null;
    String linea = "";
    String separador = ",";

    Graph  gr = new TreeMapGraph<>();
   //Vertex <DecoratedElement> a=gr.insertVertex(v);
  List <Trayecto> datosTrayectos = new <Trayecto> ArrayList();
  Iterator <Trayecto> itTrayectos=datosTrayectos.iterator();



  try {
        entrada = new Scanner(new FileReader(archivo));
        entrada.nextLine();
        boolean trayectoRepe=false;

        while (entrada.hasNextLine()) {
            linea=entrada.nextLine();
            // usa comma como separador
            String[] registro = linea.split(separador);

           idEInicial=Integer.parseInt(registro[4]);
           idEFinal=Integer.parseInt(registro[7]);
           int duracion =Integer.parseInt(registro[1]);
           datosTrayectos.add(new Trayecto());

           if((duracion<=300) && !(registro[5].equals(registro[8]))){
                while(itTrayectos.hasNext()&&(!trayectoRepe)){
                    if((itTrayectos.next().getIdEinicial() == idEInicial) && (itTrayectos.next().getIdEfinal() == idEFinal)){
                        trayectoRepe=true;
                    }

                }
            if(!trayectoRepe){
                datosTrayectos.add(new Trayecto());
            }

         }




       } 

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (!entrada.hasNextLine()) {
            entrada.close();
        }
    }   

}

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esto se debe a que estás intentando añadir elementos a tu lista mediante la cual has creado el iterador a la vez que estás iterando a través de este. Mediante esta línea:

```
datosTrayectos.add(new Trayecto());
```

Por lo tanto, el iterador, al detectar que se ha modificado la lista, no puede garantizar que itere por todos los datos correctamente. Por eso te está dando el error, ya que no puede asegurar la integridad de los datos.

Te recomiendo que te crees otra lista y uses esta lista para guardar los nuevos datos.

```
List <Trayecto> nuevosTrayectos = new <Trayecto> ArrayList();
```

Una vez finalizadas todas las iteraciones puedes utilizar el método [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) para combinar ambos `ArrayList`:

```
datosTrayectos.addAll(nuevosTrayectos);
```